# Google still has record of my old site URL - what to do?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, google-index

I had a blog site, i.e. `http://example2.com`, then I bought a new domain, i.e. `http://example.com` and 301 permanent redirected `example2.com` to `example.com`. But when I get into the Google Webmaster Tools, if I get some 404, and then click into the link and see the "Linked from" tab, it shows some links like:

- `http://example.com/post-1`
- `http://example2.com/feed`
- `http://example2.com/post-1`

[image: Google Webmaster's Tools 404 linked from]

According to Google, if you change your domain, just use a redirection for at least 4-6 months, but it almost passed. Then why Google has still traces of my old site?

The issue is important, because I don't want to pay for the old domain anymore.

I tried deleting my existing *sitemap.xml* and recreating it from the new site, but still such links are stored. What could I do?

Comment: does your new site have links to your current or old website?

Comment: Nope, I changed them all one by one.

Comment: have you got an incorrect redirect in your htaccess?

Comment: No, the basic 301 redirection is working just fine: example2.com becomes example.com when browsing.

Comment: did you implemented 301 redirect for all of your urls? maybe using .htaccess rules for redirecting every single request on example2.com (redirecting to example.com)?

Comment: .htaccess Redirect 301 is best way to tell google about changing your sitelinks. You only have to wait till google crawl understand about your site link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Webmasters also explains why the URLs are still indexed with [their YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5UJVgO2v1E). It takes a good while for the actual removal process of the old links to happen.

Also, you have to remember, Google is indexing, re-indexing, and deleting records from their Search Engine all of the time at a massive rate already, but there is trillions upon trillions of sites that this needs to be done to and more links for indexing.

Just give it some time, but the links will be updated sooner or later.

**EDIT 1**

You did all of the steps to fix the URLs indexed by Google. They just need to recrawl your website and index the links properly again.

Also, did you submit a Sitemap of all of the new URLs? That could help index your site even faster with Google WebMaster Tools.

Comment: couldn't this be quickened by clicking the fetch as google?

Comment: I am going to say yes. I, personally, have yet to use that feature of Google WebMaster Tools, but I have been told it does work and it should also speed up the process.

Comment: I've used it a couple of times and it seems like a neat tool. However, i'm not sure on how much extra priority it is given

Answer (score 0):

You can log into google webmaster tools and re-index your site. Found that is speeds up the process.

Comment: Can you provide steps/details on how to do this?